# JAMStack - Small E-commerce store

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Building a simple E-commerce store with Nuxt and Prismic.

I have this very simple action in my store:

```
async GET_ALL_CATEGORIES({commit}) {
   // gets all the categories from prismic
   // Set categories to the state
}
```

My question is, when I move around the application from `/` to `/category1` to `/category1/product1` should I be dispatching this action everytime?

Would one save this array of categories in localStorage?
Should I have an if block in my `asyncData` that checks for the `categories` state and if it is empty, dispatch the action, otherwise use whats in state?

How do the pros handle this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how often you think your 'categories from prismic' would change. If not very often then you can save it to the store and then just read from the store.

Otherwise you may want to query your API etc on every page load, probably in `mounted()`

EDIT: You many also want to set an expiry date on the state so that it can pull in fresh data at intervals

Comment: Did you mean localStorage when you said store?

Comment: @RizaKhan no, I meant the vuex store which is kept in memory. There are plugins available that allow the store to write to localStorage / cookies instead of memory. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist